# Do you want a migration path for recommendation questions from Drupal Answers?

Tags: discussion, migration

Greetings from Drupal Answers!

We've recently been asked to provide a migration path directly to your good selves on questions asking for Drupal module recommendations. The request is here: https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/add-software-recommendations-as-migration-path

Before we get too stuck into a community discussion about whether this would be a good idea, I wanted to get your feedback. If it's something you definitely don't want, that can just be that.

But if it's something the community here would be interested in, we can at least get a dialog going about if it could be accomplished in a way that's good for both sites (or, more to the point, not detrimental to SR)

You can see my general concerns about the issue on the Drupal Answers post so I won't repeat them here, but what say you?

Comment: I pared your title down a bit for easier reading in the sidebar. I believe it's still representative of what you're asking, but feel free to rollback/edit if I'm misrepresenting your question.

Answer (score 8):

My opinion on this differs from Izzy's a bit - **I'd be fine with a standard migration path** from Drupal, and from other sites where we can mutually decide it'd be a good thing.

We've grown enough that I believe we can handle the additional questions from external community-driven migrations. We can provide a good home for those, so I'd vote that we make an attempt.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm a bit paranoid or too negative. I should trust the community better. So I've upvoted your answer :) And now, don't say I'm schizophrenic #D

Comment: @Izzy Only "****a bit***"? PS: too bad meta doesn't allow bounties ... I'd right away grant +500 to this answer ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens what: paranoid or schizophrenic? #)

Comment: @Izzy You only used "a bit" in your first phrase of your prior comment, which is also what I referred to ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens then I wonder even more why you didn't pick my hint and posted your own answer. Maybe I just wanted to provoke? :) Nevermind, all fine :)

Comment: @Izzy : I intentionally did refuse from doing so. One of the reasons is that now "I" was able to upvote this answer (I wouldn't be able to do so with my own answer, right?). Though there are other reasons ...

Comment: I am also in favour of trying :-)

Comment: poor @Izzy, from ***all*** the mods on this site, you seem to be the only one who is not 100% sure ...  PS: it'll be interesting to see which of both answers over here is going to be marked as accepted some day. And if that ever happens, what will happen to my question on the related site ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens If this site decides they want the migrations, we'll make it happen.

Comment: @mpdonadio can't believe what you just wrote in your prior comment, that sounds like great news, merci! So with that all that's left is for "this site" to decide ... So fingers crossed that  the decission making process about "discussion"-tagged questions on this site will take into consideration the number of up/downvotes casted for each of the possible answers.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I am not sure why you are surprised.  Our job is the make sure to do what is right for SE.  It just happens that a lot of times, what is good for SE makes people unhappy.  You should edit in some good examples of questions into the question here so SR can see the types and quality of questions they may end up receiving.  We want to avoid the situation where we set up the migrations, and then just end up with everything being rejected.

Comment: To whom it may concern: P.I.N.G. ... Aka "***any progress to come to a conclusion***"? I mean is the answer to this question (as in its title) "yes", or is it "no"? If it is "yes", then what are the next steps to make it actually happen? Or do I need to post a new question about this comment on this site?

Answer (score 3):

I basically agree with [your answer "over there"](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3633) – especially for one reason you gave: Those who'd mark it for migration often do so "just by the name" (as folks ask questions here because they were "sent here" from another site. That is, they are not familiar with the proposed migration target, and thus should not have pushed it.

Being a mod on two SE sites, I also can agree to your understanding that "migration is extremely rare". If there happens to be a "totally matching post", people can still mark it for mod attention – and we mods have ways to cross-check amongst another when unsure.

That said, I'm not totally against it, but would "advocate against" unless overruled by the community here  – which is a call to our community to upvote my answer if you share our concerns (i.e. "vote against us becoming an official migration target) – or post an opposing answer and upvote that (while down-voting my answer).

Comment: Sorry Izzy, but I think there is something wrong in your answer, ie: "...post an opposing answer and upvote that...". I trust you know nobody can upvote (or downvote) his/her own answer. Want to try again? BTW, -1 from me for your answer, and +1 upfront for anybody who would post such opposing answer (obviously, since I started the original question on drupal.SE). PS: all my existing Questions here are "self-migrated-from-Drupal.SE" (using copy/paste variations). Are they really that bad? Do they really NOT fit here? If so please delete any of them you think don't fit.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens don't take it *too* literally :) Of course I could write "and have that upvoted" :) Go ahead, post yours then! // As I don't remember having your questions checked, I cannot tell. But in general, we had "bad migrations" quite often enough.

Comment: Thanks Izzy! I'll probably let this settle for a week or so to get a bit of exposure. Don't wish to impose, but would you be up for featuring this for a day or two? Would be great to get some more eyes on it. Won't be offended it you'd rather not :)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens time to upvote the opposite answer. I already did that :) And as for the phrasing: Checking again, I called upon the *community* to post and upvote. That's more than one person – so one posts, the others upvote #D